# Deflection percentage in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have found a deflection percentage in GtkMeter's source code and converted it to python:

```
def iec_scale(db):
  if (db < -70.0):
    defr = 0.0
  elif (db < -60.0):
    defr = (db + 70.0) * 0.25
  elif (db < -50.0):
    defr = (db + 60.0) * 0.5 + 5.0
  elif (db < -40.0):
    defr = (db + 50.0) * 0.75 + 7.5
  elif (db < -30.0):
    defr = (db + 40.0) * 1.5 + 15.0
  elif (db < -20.0):
    defr = (db + 30.0) * 2.0 + 30.0
  else:
    defr = (db + 20.0) * 2.5 + 50.0

  return defr
```

it's working perfect, except when `db = -50.0` I'm looking at code for ~1h and can't find why.

db's value => return value:

```
db = -50.1 => 9.950000
db = -50.0 => 7.500000
db = -40.1 => 14.925000
db = -40.0 => 15.000000
db = -30.1 => 29.850000
db = -30.0 => 30.000000
```

note, when `db = -50.0` there's a different behavior, instead of it be greater than value when `db = -50.1` it's smaller.

Comment: just double check this line carefully: https://github.com/swh/timemachine/blob/master/src/gtkmeter.c#L489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a typo, the proper values here are

```
  elif (db < -50.0):
    defr = (db + 60.0) * 0.5 + 2.5     # not +5.0
```

Comment: You're right, the code that I've looked is wrong also: http://djcj.org/gtk/code/gtkmeter.c